# How to new a class inside an object?

Tags: scala

I'm trying out Nak (Machine Learning package for Scala). However, they don't provide easy access for basic methods like NaiveBayes or Maximum Entropy. I want to do it manually, but I failed to create an instance of the NaiveBayes class. Part of their NaiveBayes code looks like this:

```
object NaiveBayes {
  class Trainer[L,T](wordSmoothing: Double=0.05, classSmoothing: Double= 0.01) extends Classifier.Trainer[L,Counter[T,Double]] {
    type MyClassifier = NaiveBayes[L,T]

    override def train(data: Iterable[Example[L,Counter[T,Double]]]) = {
      new NaiveBayes(data,wordSmoothing,classSmoothing)
    }
  }
}
```

I can't access the `Trainer` class...and I don't know why. The full code can be found here:

https://github.com/scalanlp/nak/blob/master/src/main/scala/nak/classify/NaiveBayes.scala

I try to write code like:

`Trainer train = new Trainer()` or `NaiveBayes.Trainer train = new ...`

It's just not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trainer` takes type parameters, so you have to specify them if they can't be inferred. For example:

```
val trainer = new NaiveBayes.Trainer[???,???]()
```

where the question marks should be replaced by type arguments for `L` and `T`. According to the comments in Classifier.scala, `L` should be the type of your labels, and `T` should be the type of your observations.

Comment: That is almost astronomical to me. Shouldn't they both be `String`s?

Comment: It really depends on your use case, right? For instance, I remember implementing a classifier to learn the oracle for a shift-reduce parser in Python where the labels were strings, but they represented one of a known finite set of operations, and I would have preferred to use some type other than strings for my labels so that I could have the advantages of static typing.

I'm sure there are many (most?) situations where all you want is strings, but it's not too hard to write `[String,String]` or write a helper function.